# Why is bash script stopping after error from foreground job?

Tags: bash, error-handling, jobs

At the start of my bash script, I am disabling the script from stopping when it comes across an error (because I want my script to continue execution in this scenario):

```
set +e
```

I then run a program as a job, run some intermediary commands, and then bring the job back into the foreground. I actually do this in a loop so that the program keeps restarting if any errors occur.

```
set -m # enable job control

while :
do
    ./my_program &
    export BOT_PID=$!
    export BOT_JID=$(jobs -l | grep -oP "\[\K[0-9]+(?=\]. $BOT_PID)")
    # ... some intermediary commands
    fg $BOT_JID
    test $? -gt 128 && break
done
```

My program is crashing which is fine, but for some reason this is causing the script to stop running, and making me regain control of the terminal that the shell script was run in.

[image]
[image]

`line 16` above refers to the `fg` command.

I can't figure out how to fix this. When my program crashes, the shell script should continue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your program exit after the loop, and what is the value of `$?` when `./my_program` crashes?

Comment: My program is ran inside the loop `./my_program`. I am then bringing the program to the foreground using `fg`, so when the program exits, the loop is supposed to continue (regardless of any error). So no, the program doesn't exit after the loop. I will check what `$?` is, maybe that is not getting assigned correctly.

Comment: In general, in a script, you should use `wait`, not `fg`. There's no good reason to turn on job control in a script; there are better tools for managing background processes that don't require it, and don't have its limitations (and focus on human/interactive use).

Comment: Also, store the PID of your background process. `./my_program & my_program_pid=$!`, then later, `wait "$my_program_pid"`

Comment: @oguzismail The value of `$?` is `134`.

Comment: which is greater than 128, and thus breaks the loop.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I need to be able to control the program (keyboard input) while it's running, which I assume is why one would use job control. This is a manually run script, so it makes sense for me to do this I think.

Comment: Or, better, `my_program_rc=0; wait "$my_program_pid" || my_program_rc=$?` -- that way you both collect the exit status _and_ mark the `wait` as "checked", so an error wouldn't be fatal _even if_ `set -e` were enabled.

Comment: @oguzismail Oh, [I found that command to check for CTRL+C and then break](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42288/320158). I didn't realize it was breaking for other return codes as well. Thanks. I will try fix to that!

Comment: If you haven't started any other jobs, `fg` with no argument will resume `my_program`.

Comment: @chepner Wow that is much simpler than the complicated command I used to find the job id! Thanks

Comment: You can also use `fg %my_prog` (any unique prefix of the command name will do) if you did need to distinguish between multiple background jobs).

Comment: @chepner Nice thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have fixed it by removing the following line:

```
test $? -gt 128 && break
```

And instead adding the above line to the top of the loop:

```
trap "exit 0" SIGINT
```